# How to define a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class in Javascript. 
This class should have

1. private and public variables and functions.
2. static and dynamic variables and functions.

How this can be done ?

Comment: This first step in proper javascript development is acceptance... accepting there is no such thing as a class in javascript...  http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: So you are down-voting this poor user because he didn't know that JavaScript doesn't have classes?

Comment: @jondavidjohn Your response is implying that the OP refuses to accept, but it's more likely that he simply didn't know...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Your response is implying that I downvoted...

Comment: I agree with Šime Vidas. Just 'cause this question is "wrong" doesn't mean it's not valuable. I'm sure there's a large number of people who would ask the same question.

Comment: I second @JHollanti - I think the community was a bit harsh on this new user

Comment: @jondavidjohn No, it isn't. I was referring to the users who down-voted ("you" as a plural). It was meant as a public response.

Comment: Its sad that somebody down-voted this question. I know that there is no class in Javascript. But my question is - is there any way to achieve this by using colsure or managing the scope of functions

Comment: @rajesh.adhi - yes, you can use closures to simulate private variables, as my answer shows.

Comment: @rajesh.adhi This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181102/javascript-classes

Comment: really in javascript if we declare a variable or an Object it is getting added as a property to the window that means every values objects and variables in javascript is having an Object path, so my question is then how we can say that java script is not an Object Oriented Language ?

Comment: @RajeshCP: I am not that much aware about javascripts, but found intresting in the question when google it got this link, looks like this one is also looking for what you need. ;)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way to create objects that support public and private properties is to use a factory function:

```
function createObj(){
   var privateVariable = "private";

   var result = {};

   result.publicProp = 12;

   result.publicMethod = function() {
      alert(this.publicProp);
      alert(privateVariable);
   };

   //this will add properties dynamically to the object in question
   result.createProperty = function (name, value) {
       this[name] = value;
   };

   return result;
}
```

As for static, you can simulate them by putting them on the function itself

```
createObj.staticProperty1 = "sorta static";
```

And to see dynamic properties in action:

```
var obj = createObj();
obj.createProperty("foo", "bar");
alert(obj.foo); //alerts bar
```